# How do you change a user password in a script with busybox and openssl?

Tags: linux, openssl, change-password, busybox

I need to synchronize a user account and password to an external source on a system with **busybox** and **openssl** installed.  When the external source tells my system to update credentials, how do I change the user's password in a script?  I will have the password in plain text.

This has to be automated, and from what I can tell busybox passwd is interactive and I don't particularly want to write an expect-type script for passwd if that's even possible.  It looks like openssl can generate password hashes (*openssl passwd -1 -salt "abcdefgh" {password}*), but will I have to modify /etc/shadow directly?

Busybox has [these](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) commands available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a small script like this to update the password. Put the following text in a file and execute it. It will change your password.

#!/bin/sh

passwd << EOF

<old password>

<new password>

<new password>

EOF

Answer (score 8):

Turns out current versions of busybox have [chpasswd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chpasswd) ([source code](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/loginutils/chpasswd.c)).  chpasswd takes a colon-delimited pair username:password on stdin.  I don't know whether I can update the busybox on my system, but I'll leave this answer in case someone else comes looking.

From the busybox documentation:

```
chpasswd
chpasswd [--md5|--encrypted]

Read user:password from stdin and update /etc/passwd

Options:

        -e,--encrypted  Supplied passwords are in encrypted form
        -m,--md5        Use MD5 encryption instead of DES
```